# How do I compile my app for a specific iOS device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I need to compile my app (when archiving) specifically for the iPhone 6S Plus because my `.ipa` file is too large according to the WWDC scholarship application guidelines. How can I only compile for the 6S Plus, thereby making my `.ipa` file way smaller?

Comment: Your zipped .ipa is over 100MB? There isn't really a way to compile an app for only one device; but you *might* be able to safe some space by ripping out all the image files except the @3x versions. I'm applying too; best of luck!

Comment: Do you have a paid membership of the developer program?

Answer (score 0):

From menus bar choose `Product-->Archive--->Export---->save for development deployment.`
after it choose any device that you want.
[image]

Comment: Note that this assumes that App Thinning is enabled. It probably is, but it's questionable how much space that'll net you.